# Auto update textbox as you type with node/socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http

I have a little node.js app with sockets. My goal is to have one machine open with my webpage, and a seperate machine open with the same webpage. When I paste text into the page on machine 1, I want that to auto update on machine 2. when i paste text on machine 2, i want that previous text to be erased from machine 1, and be updated with the text from machine 2.

currently i have the page running in two seperate browser windows. in machine 1 i type "a", on machine 2 appears "a".

on machine 1 i type "b", on machine 2 appears "ab". it is constantly appending!

**video**: http://instagram.com/p/jVIgTZE2Ib/

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<textarea id="chat"></textarea>
    <!-- <textarea size="35" id="message"></textarea> -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
jQuery(function($){

    var socket = io.connect();
    // var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
    // var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $chat.keyup(function(e){
        // var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        // if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode

                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $chat.val());

        // }
    });

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        // $chat.val('');
        $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was change:

```
socket.on('new message', function(data){
        $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
    });
```

to

```
socket.on('new message', function(data){
    $chat.val(data);
});
```

Comment: Hehehe, yep.. I like how you said "It is constantly appending" and then reading through the code it went "append" :)

Comment: Yeah, 99% of my errors are like the most obvious ones ever haha.